# Execution Timeout on dropping a constraint

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using powershell and bcp to load thousands of files into a table. For each data file, I use create a default value for a column I want filled. I then remove that default value, and add a new one for the next file, and so on for all of them.

The code is here:

```
$query = "alter table $tableName add constraint DF_temp_jobID_$tableName default $dir_id for jobID"
$sqlCmd2 = $connection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCmd2.Connection = $connection
$sqlCmd2.CommandText = $query
$sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader()
bcp "$tableName" in "$dir_id${string}.csv" -f "formatFile_file.fmt" -U 
$query = "alter table $tableName drop constraint DF_temp_jobID_$tableName"
$sqlCmd3 = $connection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCmd3.Connection = $connection
$sqlCmd3.CommandText = $query
$sqlCmd3.ExecuteReader()
```

I've deleted identifying information from the bcp command. This code is running on loop thousands of times, once for each data file. At a certain point, I get the following timeout error.

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
```

This error is happening fairly quickly. The default timeout is 600s or something. I'm not waiting even close to that long. I don't understand why you'd have a timeout on dropping or adding a constraint. That feels like it should be a constant-time operation, or close to it.

Comment: I'd bet something has a lock on that table. Run [**sp_WhoIsActive**](http://whoisactive.com/) and see what is blocking you...

Comment: But wouldn't it happen sooner? Like it gets through a few hundred files, then just randomly stops on a later file after only waiting like 15 seconds.

Comment: Not sure why it only waits 15 seconds, unless it becomes a deadlock victim. You should see this in the SQL Server error log if it is deadlocked though.

Comment: I'll run the script again and see if I can find a deadlock.

Comment: Oh, as it happens, it can't just be related to the size of the bcp insertion. It fails with a timeout on something with 109,000 rows, but then succeeds on one afterward with 120k rows. Something weird is happening. Oh, and I'm connecting to a server on Azure.

Comment: That's not a lot of rows for BCP so i wouldn't think that would be it. I'm not even sure BCP has a limit--people use it to migrate entire databases.

Comment: The issue isn't bcp. BCP succeeds always.  The issue is with the queries independent of BCP. (the dropping and adding constraints)

Comment: Any luck with the blocking check?

Comment: Nope, I don't think it's related to a deadlock. Really appreciate the help!